# Problem using Jar file in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, jar, sdk, bixolon-printer

I've  converted a **Jar SDK** of Bixolon pos printer to `dll`, using *Xamarin binding library*, but I received the error:

```
Java.Lang.Error: Provider mf.org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration not found
```

When I run `dll` library in my Xamarin android project.

Also the class

```
mf.org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration
```

existed in **Jar** file when I converted it  to `dll`.

Can you help me solve this problem?